# Human-readable or SEO-friendly URL in secure application

Tags: url, seo

I am working on an application that has no public content.  All users must have an account and must be logged in to see anything of significance.  In this case, what are the arguments for/against human-readable URL's?

As far as I can see, there is no need for the URLs to be SEO-friendly (since search engines can not access the site).  I don't need users to be able to cut/paste URLs to share them with each other, and there's no need for them to use the address bar to navigate (i.e. no need for them to guess URL's).

I can't see any argument for making the URL's sensible, but am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnConde: I’d say this question is especially *not* about SEO (→ "search engines can not access the site").

Answer (score 2):

There is a possible benefit in that the URLs will be more (as you say in your title) human readable and maybe easier to remember for your users.

You seem to feel strongly about the users of this site not needing to cut and paste to share, but maybe there are some edge cases worth considering? For example, if a user wants to copy and paste a URL for their own use later on a URL that makes semantic sense might be easier for them to look at a week or month later and immediately know what it's for. That said, you may not feel strongly about supporting this type of use case.

Consider, too, possibly for your benefit in providing support. If a user can give you a URL that is immediately obvious because of its structure, then that *could* help you figure out their issues more quickly. But that will all depend on your specific application.

There is one thing for certain: implementing these type of URLs now won't **hurt** your users. So if you can and it's within your time constraints then why not?